# Avoiding SQL injection using FMDB

Tags: ios, objective-c, sql-injection, fmdb

I'm trying to update my db model to avoid injection attacks. I'm confused for some of the queries on how to apply data binding.

For example here is one such query:

```
   FMResultSet *results = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT ifnull(FirstName,'') ||' '|| ifnull(LastName,'') FROM Contacts Where PK = ? ",pk];
```

Do I need to really bind the second null argument in the ifnull() even though I'm not passing any argument ?

Is this a safe way to do  or should I do something like:

```
   FMResultSet *results = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT ifnull(FirstName, ?) ||' '|| ifnull(LastName,?) FROM HHCContacts Where PK = ? ",@"",@"",pk];
```